# git: restore folder and all subfolders/files under a different name

Tags: git

On the `master` branch, I have new version of the folder with files in it, e.g.:

```
config
  - db
    - rdbms
      - postgres.conf
      - redis.conf
    - nosql
      - mongo.conf
  - web
    - apache.conf
  - security.conf
```

I need to take older version of these files and add them to the master but the top folder `config` should be renamed to `config-old`, so that both `config` and `config-old` are present:

```
config
  - db
    - rdbms
      - postgres.conf
      - redis.conf
    - nosql
      - mongo.conf
  - web
    - apache.conf
  - security.conf

config-old
  - db
    - rdbms
      - postgres.conf
      - redis.conf
    - nosql
      - mongo.conf
  - web
    - apache.conf
    - nginx.conf
```

I know how to use `git show` or `git cat-file` to restore individual files and using shell redirection I can save them under another name, but how do I do this with an entire folder and all subfolder/subfiles in it?

Obviously, I can just switch to the required branch/revision, copy the folder somewhere outside of the git root, switch back to master and then copy back under different name, but I wonder if this can be done with git itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it quite easily with *basic* commands:

```
git checkout $OLD_VERSION
cp -R config config-old
git checkout master
```

At this point `config-old` is untracked so:

```
git add config-old
git commit -m 'Copy config from $OLD_VERSION to config-old'
```

Comment: Tada! Indeed, why have I missed this?! Thank you!

Comment: That's a simpler / more obvious way to do it. Nice :) However: Be careful using this in case you have .gitignore'd files in `config/`. Those files will be copied as well and can possibly end up tracked by accident (if their .gitignore-patterns are limited to their original folder).
Also you may run into problems (checkout cancelled) with an unclean `git status`.

Answer (score 2):

If you create an empty folder `config-old` beforehand,
you can use `git archive` to get `config/` from the revision of your choice
and extract it to the folder `config-old/` like this:

```
git archive --format=tar <COMMIT/BRANCH/TAG> -- config | tar --extract --directory=./config-old --strip-components=1
```